# Constructor for class must explicitly initialize the base class

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, namespaces, multiple-inheritance

I've got:

```
//all classes are in different files
namespace Tree {
    class Node {
        NodeType type;
    protected:
        std::string nodename;
        Node(Node::NodeType _type) : type(_type) {}
    };
}

class Parent : public virtual Tree::Node {
protected:
    Parent() : Node(Node::UNDEFINED) {}
};

class Child: public virtual Tree::Node {
protected:
    Child() : Node(Node::UNDEFINED) {}
};

namespace Tree {
    class Element :
             public Parent,
             public Child,
             public virtual Node {

    protected:
        Element() : Node(Node::ELEMENT) {}
    };
}

class SpecificElement: public Tree::Element {
public:
    SpecificElement(const std::string name) {
        nodename = name;
    }
};
```

In the constructor of `SpecificElement` appears the error:

> Constructor for 'SpecificElement' must explicitly initialize the base
>   class 'Tree::Node' which does not have a default contructor

Isn't Node supposed to be initialized through Element?, why the compiler ask me for explicitly initialize there?

I don't know if this has anything to do with the builders being protected. Or if it is for the namespaces, although, I don't think so, since the code compiled, until I introduced the class `SpecificElement`.

I would call the constructor of Node in `SpecificElement`, but I have many more classes that inherit from this, and in all asks me to initialize explicitly Node, and I can not do that by design.

**EDIT:**
thanks to @r-sahu, I solved it as follow

```
namespace Tree {
    class Node {
    protected:
        std::string nodename;
        NodeType type; //changed to protected

        Node(Node::NodeType _type) : type(_type) {}
        Node() : Node(UNDEFINED) {} //default constructor
    };
}

namespace Tree {
    class Element :
             public Parent,
             public Child,
             public virtual Node {

    protected:
        Element() { //change the init constructor list
            type = Node::ELEMENT; //change type inside constructor
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't Element call the Ctor of Node explicitly?

Comment: Is no needed, because now Node has a `default` constructor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Isn't `Node` supposed to be initialized through `Element`?, why the compiler ask me for explicitly initialize there?

No.

That happens only when you create an instance of `Element`, not a sub-class of `Element`. This has to do with `virtual` inheritance.

Classes that are `virtual`ly inherited must be initialized correctly in the constructor of the most derived class. Hence, you must use:

```
SpecificElement(const std::string name) : Tree::Node(Node::ELEMENT) {
    nodename = name;
}
```

With that in place, when you construct an instance of `SpecificElement`, the `Tree::Node` sub-object is initialized only once, from the constructo of `SpecificElement`. The `Tree::Node(Node::Element)` part in the constructor of `Element` is ignored at runtime.

The justification for this behavior can be found in the standard in [Section 12.6.2 Initializing bases and members/10.1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/class.base.init#10.1)

Comment: when I set a default constructor to `Node`, it seems that the constructor for `Element` is not called, all my nodes are of type `UNDEFINED`

Comment: @quetzalfir, the constructor of `Element` is called but initialization of `Tree::Node` is done only from the most derived class. You can add a `std::cout << "In Element()\n"` in the body of the constructor of `Element` to verify that.